# What are some useful resources for modal study?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-progressions, modes, cadence

I'm looking for some useful historical references for modal study. Specifically, great books or texts on how modes evolved, progressed and became the elusive subject they are today.

What resources have been useful to you to have it finally click? I would imagine there are some basic texts in the formal music school context so I'm looking for anything like that, but useful videos that made the difference for you are also good.

I'm feeling pretty solid on my diatonic tonal study and want to branch out into modal studies with a solid foundation of how they evolved.

Comment: I would be remiss not to add this to the thread - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)#Modern_modes - Creating chord progressions or leveraging melodic intent of "Modern Modes" is the end-game - but I'm also fascinated by the predecessors to modern modes and would love any texts on the subject.

Comment: Hi Glen. Although we don't offer the kinds of references you're looking for, there are many posts here dealing with modal music, both modern and ancient, and some may include the kinds of resources you're looking for. As a starting point, try searching for the tags [tag:modes] or [tag:modal]. (Clicking on either of those links in this comment will execute the search for you.)